# Disable button on UI after Click and successful Ajax API call

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I am a newcomer to the world of Jquery and Ajax. I have a page which has table containing list of customers and the movies which they have rented. Against each column is a 'Check-In' button. Once the user click on this button, an API is called which updates the current date time in the back end table which then reflects on the UI.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CheckIn";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CheckIn</h2>

<table id="rentals" class="table    table-bordered  table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @*<th>Rental Id</th>*@
            <th>Customer Id</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Movie Id</th>
            <th>Movie Name</th>
            <th>Date Rented</th>
            <th>Date Returned</th>
            <th>Check-In</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /*Logic To map the data to the table*/
            var rentalTable = $("#rentals").DataTable({
                /*using ajax to call the api*/
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/rentals",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                /*Specify Column Mappings*/
                columns: [
                    { data: "customersId" },
                    { data: "customersName" },
                    { data: "movieId" },
                    { data: "movieName" },
                    { data: "dateRented" },
                    { data: "dateReturned" },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function (data) {
                                return "<button class ='btn-link js-checkin' data-rental-id =" + data + ">Check-In</button>"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });


            $("#rentals").on("click", ".js-checkin", function () {
                var button = $(this);

                // get the current row
                //https://codepedia.info/jquery-get-table-cell-td-value-div
                var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
                var custId = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
                var movId = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD

                var rentalData = { customerId: custId, movieId: movId }
                button.attr("disabled", true);

                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to check in this movie ?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/rentals",
                            method: "put",
                            data: rentalData,
                            success: function () {
                                
                                $('#rentals').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

Currently when I click on the Check in Button, it calls the API, updates the data in the DB table and the table on the UI gets reloaded to reflect the Date Time added.

[Screenshot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeyCs.png)

I need help in disabling this 'Check-In' button once it is clicked on and the Ajax call is successful, because the user can keep clicking the button again and again even after the API call is successful and the data is updated in DB.

```
<button class ='btn-link js-checkin' data-rental-id =" + data + ">Check-In</button>"
```

I have tried to add the lines of code which are currently commented in order to disable the button but none of them worked.

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to check in this movie ?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/rentals",
                            method: "put",
                            data: rentalData,
                            success: function () {

                                //$(".js-checkin").attr("disabled", true);
                                //$('.js-checkin').prop('disabled', true);
                                //$(this).prop('disabled', true);

                                //var button = rentalTable.buttons(['.js-checkin'])
                                //rentalTable.row(button.remove()).draw();

                                $('#rentals').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Add a class to the button (`button.addClass('checked-in');`) and in the class set `pointer-events: none;`, along with any styling you require to make the button look disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<script>
//code to check if api call is successful and if so run the below code
//document.getElementById("button1").disable=true
</script>
```